# Break the quantity (number) in a record and set them as array for option selection

Tags: javascript, php, sql

For example, There has been customer who has bought 4 of Product-One. And it has been insert to the table.

Product Table:

```
   ----------------------------------
   Product             quantity             
   ----------------------------------
   Product-One           4
```

When customer bought that, they had not decided that they want to get the product at that time. They just want to save it with us. Next day, when the costumer need the product, they ask us to deliver the product.

Since they had bought 4 of PRoduct-One, they can choose how many product they want us to deliver it to them.

And now I don't know how to break the number of quantity, for example in product-One who has 4 quantity become 1,2,3,4 in dropdown selection.

```
   <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
   <select>
```

Anybody help me,please. It is getting complicated for me. :/

Here is my blur php code:

```
                    <table id="canvasEstockTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Product</td>
                            <td>Quantity</td>
                            <td>Pick</td>
                        </tr>

            <?php           
            $resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE member_name = '$member_name' ORDER BY id ASC");
                if ($resultsTicket > 0) {
                    while($obj = $resultsTicket->fetch_object()) {

                echo'       <tr>
                            <td>$obj->product_name</td>
                            <td>$obj->quantity</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="quantity" required>
                                    <option value="">Choose Quantity</option>

                                    //IT SHOULD BE LOOPING AUTOMATICALLY HERE//
                                    <option value="{$Quantity_1}">'.{$Quantity_1}.'</option>
                                    <option value="{$Quantity_2}">'.{$Quantity_2}.'</option>
                                    <option value="{$Quantity_3}">'.{$Quantity_3}.'</option>
                                    <option value="{$Quantity_4}">'.{$Quantity_4}.'</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';

                    }
                }
            ?>

                    </table>
```

---

---

[UPDATE HERE]

```
            <?php           
            $resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders_history WHERE customer_name = '$member_name' ORDER BY id ASC");
                if ($resultsTicket > 0) {
                    while($obj = $resultsTicket->fetch_object()) {

                echo'       <tr>
                            <td>'.$obj->items.'</td>
                            <td>'.$obj->quantity.'</td>
                            <td>

                                <select name="quantity" required>

                                    <option value="">Choose Quantity</option>

                                        for ($q = 1; $q <= $obj->quantity; $q++) {
                                            <option value="'.$q.'">'.$q.'</option>                                          
                                        } 

                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>';

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sidenote:: Variables do not interpolate inside single quotes. Therefore, `$obj->product_name` and `$obj->quantity` will not fire up. You need to concatenate those as well.

Comment: It just for an example. My problem now is on how to break the quantity into numbers. Pleasssssssseeeeeeeee

Comment: No need of specifying `ASC` in `order by` since that's the default.

Comment: Gawd I love examples.

Comment: Regarding your update `for ($q = 1; $q <= $obj->quantity; $q++)` you're doing it again, or is that another example?

Comment: Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Change your `echo'` to `echo "` and `</tr>';` to `</tr>";`, invert the quotes inside your present concatenated variables and the `for` loop will work. You can also try going in and out of PHP as shown in the answer below. Nonetheless, variables inside single quoted echoes will not work.

Comment: Plus, if you don't have short tags set/enabled in your system, then using `<?=` in the answer below won't work. Those will need to be changed to `<?php echo`, so that could be a contributing factor as to why the answer didn't work.

Comment: However, with that said. I doubt you can run a function inside an echo.

Comment: How about doing this with javascript?

Comment: I'm not the person to ask about JS, sorry.

Comment: I am even not sure if you are good enogh in php :)

Comment: *"I am even not sure if you are good enogh in php"* - That's not a very nice thing to say. I'm not about to setup a whole script/DB to fix this. I'm not paid for this you know. Good luck with that. I'm moving on. Take it up with the answer below, *ciao!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Who ask that you will be paid for this or not? Oh, come on, man. It's not about money. It's about rocking the world with your reputation. I hope what you got in PHP programming can satisfy your life when you keep it for yourself. Good luck, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop:

```
<?php           
$resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE member_name = '$member_name' ORDER BY id ASC");
if ($resultsTicket > 0) {
   while($obj = $resultsTicket->fetch_object()) {
   ?>
   <tr>
     <select name="quantity" required>
       <option value="">Choose Quantity</option>
        <?php
        for ($q = 1; $q <= $obj->quantity; $q++) {
        ?>
           <option value="<?=$q?>">Quantity <?=$q?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>
   </tr>
<?php } %>
```

Comment: Will it break the quantity into a number?

Comment: I used `$Quantity` generically here, as i don't know your schema.  It might be something like $obj->quantity or whatever's in your database.  But, assuming it contains a number like 4, this loop will draw 4 "<options>".  Which, i think, is your question.

Comment: Yes it is my question. Thanks, I will give it a try soon as I am a little tired to think now. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at my update question, and it doesn't work to achieve what I need.

Comment: the "for..." provided in my answer is PHP, not HTML and cannot be wrapped in a giant `echo`.  See my example where i turn on php with `<%php...`

Comment: I have tried to do that will all the codes you provided to me. But it didn't work. And I change the structure, and it still didn't work.

Comment: I change `$q=1;` to `$q=0;` and it shows `<select>quantity 0</select>` When it is '1' it doesn't show `<select>quantity 1</select>`

Comment: What is the value of `$obj->quantity`.  It must be zero for some reason.